# Exporting shapes from Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

Is there a way to export shapes (included vector clipart) that are preinstalled with MS Visio?

Copy/paste only copies them as bitmaps, without preserving the transparency. I also tried to export the entire drawing to EMF, WMF and several other formats, but my other app (Corel Paint Shop Pro) was unable to read them (showing only a blank page).

Did you have similar problems? I would appreciate if I could get the vector format somehow, or at least a transparent PNG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right click the stencil heading of the stencil that contains the shape you want (e.g. Blocks).
2. Click Edit Stencil.
3. Right click the shape.
4. Click Edit Master > Edit Master Shape.
5. Click File > Save As and pick SVG or whatever.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Actually, all `Edit stencil` menu items were disabled in my document (Visio 2007), as well as `Edit master` menu items. I had to open the Document stencil (File -> Shapes -> Show document stencil), and then edit those shapes which are present in the file. Not sure why it was disabled, but you gave me the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have had success exporting libraries as a stencil and then importing those stencils into another program that supports stencils. If you are looking for a transparent png you can use Lucidchart.

Import visio stencil, open up new document, drag out the shapes you need. Once you have what you want.

**File** > **download as** > **transparent PNG** (you also have the option to select what part of the document you want of document you want to export.

Comment: On this and any future posts in which you recommend Lucidchart, you need to disclose that you are the marketing director for the product.  If what you describe requires one of the paid versions, you should mention that, also.  There is nothing wrong with providing a good answer, that is an actual solution to the question (like you did here), based on your own product.  However, failing to disclose your connection could lead to the post being treated as spam.